# expected <class 'float'>" Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am creating an API to get data from django model to excel sheet.

While doing so i am getting the error mentioned in the title.

models.py

```
class Task(models.Model):

    Id=models.IntegerField()
    Name=models.CharField(max_length=50,null=False,blank=True)
    Image1=models.FileField(blank=True, default="",
     upload_to="media/images",null=True)
    Image2=models.FileField(blank=True, default="",
     upload_to="media/images",null=True)
    Date=models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.Name)
```

views.py

```
class TaskViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def list(self,request):

        try:
            queryset=Task.objects.all()
            response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/ms-excel')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="users.xls'
            wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
            ws = wb.active
            ws.title = "Your Title"

            row_num=0
            columns=['Id','Name','Image1','Image2','Date']

            for col_num in range(len(columns)):
                c = ws.cell(row=row_num + 1, column=col_num + 1)
                c.value = columns[col_num][0]
                ws.column_dimensions[get_column_letter(col_num + 1)].width = columns[col_num][1]
            for obj in queryset:
                row_num += 1
                row = [
                    obj.Id,
                    obj.Name,
                    obj.Image1,
                    obj.Image2,
                    obj.Date,
                ]
                for col_num in range(len(row)):
                    c = ws.cell(row=row_num + 1, column=col_num + 1)
                    c.value = row[col_num]
            
            wb.save(response)
            return response
        
        except Exception as error:
            traceback.print_exc()
            return Response({"message": str(error), "success": False}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ashu/Desktop/django/task/office/views.py", line 54, in list
    ws.column_dimensions[get_column_letter(col_num + 1)].width = columns[col_num][1]
  File "/home/ashu/Desktop/django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/base.py", line 67, in __set__
    value = _convert(self.expected_type, value)
  File "/home/ashu/Desktop/django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/base.py", line 57, in _convert
    raise TypeError('expected ' + str(expected_type))
TypeError: expected <class 'float'>
```

Comment: Please add the full error stacktrace.

Comment: @Ralf  Traceback: Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/ashu/Desktop/django/task/office/views.py", line 54, in list ws.column_dimensions[get_column_letter(col_num + 1)].width = columns[col_num][1]

File "/home/ashu/Desktop/django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/base.py", line 67, in set value = _convert(self.expected_type, value)

File "/home/ashu/Desktop/django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/base.py", line 57, in _convert raise TypeError('expected ' + str(expected_type))

TypeError: expected <class 'float'>

Answer (score -1):

This line of your code seems wrong:

```
ws.column_dimensions[get_column_letter(col_num + 1)].width = columns[col_num][1]
```

You defined

```
columns = ['Id','Name','Image1','Image2','Date']
```

So the part `columns[col_num][1]` would return single char (`columns[col_num]` is a string, and `[1]` returns the second char from that string.)

But `ws.column_dimensions[get_column_letter(col_num + 1)].width` should be a float, not a string/char.

Comment: so what should i do now,can i make it comment?

Answer (score -1):

It means that the size of the columns of your file, one of them must have a size in decimal, which conflicts with the library, I recommend that the sizes be whole numbers.

I would recommend generating a validated column length with another excel reading engine, such as win32com to set the columns to an integer value.

```
import win32com.client as win32
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Add()
ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
ws.Range("A1:A10").Value = "A"
ws.Range("B1:B10").Value = "This is a very long line of text"
ws.Columns(1).ColumnWidth = 1
ws.Range("B:B").ColumnWidth = 27
wb.SaveAs('column_widths.xlsx')
excel.Application.Quit()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as code, citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.